# print source code evolution in time

Tags: printing

My program during time has become quite large, and I have access to a A0 plotter.

I'd like to print side-by-side successive versions of the code, in meld (http://meldmerge.org/) style, or similar (i.e. enhancing the differences between versions).

Do you know which tool I could use?

Answer (score 0):

something interesting at *Gource* https://code.google.com/p/gource/, but I dont keep my program under a repository, so that's not for me

Comment: if you not used version control system how you would to find a time difference ?

Comment: if you have archived versionsyou can just committhem one by one to repository

Comment: the time diff? Simply by the file mod. date. And I prefer not to use a repository...